# how to whitelist aws VPC to remote service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have create a VPC with public and private subnets. Setup internet gateway and nat gateway in route table. I am using some 3rd party api services who needs to whitelist IP to access their API. 
my question is it possible to whitelist my VPC to their API and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by IP whitelisting. How many of your IP addresses can they whitelist? How many EC2 instances are you planning to launch? Are you going to launch these EC2 instances manually or are they part of auto-scaling group?

If you are going to have a few manually launched EC2 instances then you can assign Elastic IP address to each one of them, tell the 3rd party to whitelist those Elastic IPs and if your EC2 instance fails, just remap Elastic IP to another instance - replacement. This of course holds true only if you plan to launch your EC2 instances in a public subnet.

If you are going to have many EC2 instances, launched either manually or via auto-scaling group, then you will have to route egress traffic to that 3rd party provider via NAT Gateway (or NAT instance, or some custom proxy but the idea stays the same) with assigned Elastic IP address and tell them to whitelist that Elastic IP attached to NAT Gateway (for high availability, you might want to use multiple NAT Gateways in multiple AZs, each one with Elastic IP).

One thing to note here is that you will need to place your EC2 instances and your NAT Gateway into different subnets because you will need at least 2 route tables. One for NAT Gateway's subnet with entry to Internet Gateway `0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW` and the other for subnet where your EC2 instances are with entry `0.0.0.0/0 -> NAT Gateway`. This holds true for both public and private instances.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, my EC2 are auto scaled. I will use elastic beanstalk to use those 3rd parties. and my beanstalk will be contained into VPC.